# Dynamic number of columns with values from another column

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL. There may be varying numbers of m_id's, so we need a varying number of columns.

I need to get from:

```
time (timestamp), mid, mvalue
2023-xx1, 2, 11.2
2023-xx1, 4, 11.4
2023-xx1, 3, 9.3
2023-xx1, 1, 1.2
2023-xx2, 2, 7.6
2023-xx2, 4, 4.8
2023-xx2, 3, 6.3
2023-xx2, 1, 5.2
```

to:

```
time, mid1, mid2, mid3, mid4
2023-xx1, 1.2, 11.2, 9.3, 11.4   
2023-xx2, 5.2, 7.6, 6.3, 4.8
```

There has to be a smart SQL way of doing this but I have not found anything so far. Setup:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mvalues;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mvalues
(time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL, mid character varying(200), mvalue numeric(16,5));

INSERT INTO public.mvalues(time, mid, mvalue) VALUES ('2023-01-01 01:01:01', 2, 11.2);
INSERT INTO public.mvalues(time, mid, mvalue) VALUES ('2023-01-01 01:01:01', 4, 11.4);
INSERT INTO public.mvalues(time, mid, mvalue) VALUES ('2023-01-01 01:01:01', 3, 9.3);
INSERT INTO public.mvalues(time, mid, mvalue) VALUES ('2023-01-01 01:01:01', 1, 1.2);
INSERT INTO public.mvalues(time, mid, mvalue) VALUES ('2023-01-01 02:01:01', 2, 7.6);
INSERT INTO public.mvalues(time, mid, mvalue) VALUES ('2023-01-01 02:01:01', 4, 4.8);
INSERT INTO public.mvalues(time, mid, mvalue) VALUES ('2023-01-01 02:01:01', 3, 6.3);
INSERT INTO public.mvalues(time, mid, mvalue) VALUES ('2023-01-01 02:01:01', 1, 5.2);
```

Thanks

Comment: The keyword to search for is "pivot".

Comment: You can't have a dynamic number of columns in a SQL query. A fundamental restriction of the SQL language is, that the number, names and data types of all columns of a query must be know to the database _before_ it starts retrieving data.

Comment: This is correct  @a_horse_with_no_name. Thank you. Don't know what I was thinking.